# Mysql соединение для демона

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

Пишу проект, в котором серверная часть на PHP запускается в режиме демона, т.е. в теории должна проработать не выключаясь годами. Я подключаюсь к базе данных mysql по средствам mysqli при старте сервера и дальше он работает с объектом. Так вот спустя какое-то время, примерно меньше суток, закрывается соединение на mysqli и пиши пропало.
Я нашел библиотеку которая использует PDO и в ней предусмотрена ситуация в которой происходит разъединение, но почитав интернет так сказать, я обнаружил что PDO использует mysql драйвер (он же вроде как является устаревшим и все переходят на mysqli) или я запутался в определении драйвера и библиотеки ? Является ли PDO таким же прогрессивным решением как и Mysqli по сравнению с Mysql ?

Comment: вот это у вас каша в голове))) расширение для php `mysql_*` - устаревшее. C PDO всё в порядке

Comment: Что mysql, что mysqli, что PDO могут работать через один и тот же драйвер http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqlnd.php

Comment: под драйвером подразумевается в общем случае соединение с самой субд: MySQL, MSSQL, Postgre, Firebird, SQLite и пр.

Comment: Разрыв соединения, это нормальная рабочая ситуация. Существует куча причин, по которым оно может порваться. Делаете свою функцию отправки запроса в БД и если при запросе возникает разрыв соединения (определяете по кодам ошибок) то пытаетесь переподключиться и повторить запрос. главное не делать это при других ошибках (ошибки в самом запросе) и не зациклиться на этом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Устаревшим является не драйвер mysql, а расширение mysql в php.

PDO и mysqli являются "прогрессивными решениями" - да. Если у Вас есть уже решение на mysqli - не вижу смысла менять всё на PDO (хотя оно мне и больше нравится).

По поводу саморазрывающегося соединения - а почему бы Вам не закрывать его самому? Это один из немногих случаев, когда это имеет смысл делать. Если я правильно Вас понял - вы совершаете какое-то действие, а потом до следующего "действия" ничего не происходит - так и закройте соединение. Когда понадобится - заново откроете (ну только если Вы не собираетесь это делать каждую секунду).

P.S. ну и однозначно плюсик автору вопроса за использование mysqli. Поставил бы и второй, за упоминание PDO, но нельзя.